# conditional logic in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the following conditional logic with regular expression.

```
if (text starts with +61) {
  if (text after +61 is 1800) {
    // then match 6 digits after 1800. So, the regex until here should be +611800 and then 6 digits
  } else {
    // match 9 digits after +61
  }
}
```

I read on how to write conditional regular expressions. But, I'm stuck here with the following regular expression

```
^\+61((?=1800)\d{6}|\d{9})$
```

The above regex fails for this, but it has to be successful

- +611800123456 (This has to be success)

And the following text passes the regex test but it has to fail

- +61180012345 (This has to be fail)

Here are my tests in regexr site.

https://regexr.com/5ia2e

Comment: Just use `^\+61(?:1800\d{6}|\d{9})$`, `(?=1800)\d{6}` means the first four digits matched with `\d{6}` must be `1800`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that. It is matching +61180012345. This has to fail as there are only 5 digits after 1800

Comment: Then use `^\+61(?:1800\d{6}|(?!1800)\d{9})$`. Since there is no conditional construct in JS regex, you just need to use lookaheads to negate a specific pattern at the start of the alternative.

Comment: Thanks guys. It worked. Can you explain the ?! in the answer. I can mark as answer

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can post it if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(?=1800)\d{6}` pattern means the first four digits matched with `\d{6}` must be `1800`, while you want to match any six digits after `1800` substring. That means, you need to "convert" the non-consuming `(?=1800)` into a consuming `1800` pattern.

Also, note that `\d{9}` second alternative will match any nine digits, while you only want to match them if they do not start with `1800`. You need to prepend that second alternative with a `(?!1800)` negative lookahead pattern. Unfortunately, JavaScript RegExp does not support *conditional constructs*, in PCRE, .NET, etc. you [could use](https://regex101.com/r/jILUcQ/1) `^\+61(?(?=1800)1800\d{6}|\d{9})$`, but not in this case.

Here, you can use

```js
^\+61(?:1800\d{6}|(?!1800)\d{9})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regexr.com/5ia5q).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\+61` - `+61` substring
- `(?:1800\d{6}|(?!1800)\d{9})` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `1800\d{6}`  - `1800` substring and then any six digits
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!1800)\d{9}` - any nine digits not starting with `1800`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I did not quit get the last part `(?!1800)\d{9}` in [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) they are using different syntax, can you please elaborate on that part?

Comment: @AlanOmar `(?!1800)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `1800` char sequence immediately to the right of the current location. MDN only supplies some examples, they are not using any different syntax.

Comment: Yes i get now so if `?:1800\d{6}` did not match. the regex become `^\+61(?!1800)\d{9}$` which will match any nine digits not starting with`1800`, thank you very much.